# social media feeds and json/xml data through api call?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-social

I am looking for a way so that i will call the api and get the data based on my input or search data from multiple of social media sites like facebook, linkedin, twitter, google+.

Data format will be prefer if it will be in json or xml.
social feeds i already tried but it is not giving the proper data what i am looking for.

Is there any github project anyone know in spring + hibernate, so please help me. I am also looking for some api configuration from separate social media sites. Currently i am trying..

I am mentioning some of the best link i am found ....

[Spring Social:](https://projects.spring.io/spring-social/) that will allow to connect some of the top social media sites.

[Top 10 Social APIs: Facebook, Twitter and Google Plus](https://www.programmableweb.com/news/top-10-social-apis-facebook-twitter-and-google-plus/analysis/2015/02/17)

[39 Must-Have APIs for Developers](https://blog.profitbricks.com/39-must-have-apis-for-developers/)

[Authenticating a Twitter Feed for OAuth API V1.1 - Timelines & streams](https://tomelliott.com/php/authenticating-twitter-feed-timeline-oauth)

[Social Searcher](https://www.social-searcher.com/)

[Spring Social Project](https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-spring-social)

[Video Tutorial spring social](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJJRamEl_u0&list=PLwIFo6ewnySUoZGk-9w7tauadYHA3zxan)

LinkedIn: https://developer.linkedin.com/apis

Last.fm: http://www.last.fm/api

Youtube: https://developers.google.com/youtube/

Flickr: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/

Google Dev: https://developers.google.com/

Yahoo Dev: https://developer.yahoo.com/

Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/

Twitter: https://dev.twitter.com/

http://mashable.com/2009/05/21/social-media-api/